# VMWare debug beeping from guest to host broken?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, audio, vmware

I'm on a Windows 10 as hypervisor running VMWare Workstation Player 16, having a guest OS running Ubuntu 22.04 with the `xubuntu-desktop` package installed,
and sound is working fine, running audio/video from VLC works fine, but console beeps do not work, how should i debug this? I've run out of ways to debug it.

Things i've tried:

- setting `mks.noBeep = "FALSE"` in the .vmx file (i think FALSE is the default anyway, but doesn't hurt to make sure)
- making sure audio works fine: it does (VLC mp3 playback works fine)
- tried both in xfce4-terminal and gnome-terminal, beep doesn't work in either.
- tried beeping with both `echo -ne "\a"` and the [ncurses beep api](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/beep.html), it doesn't matter, there's no beep.
- ensured "System Sounds" are not silenced in Volume Control: it isn't. [image]
  ... and I'm stuck. suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

From the post
[Passthrough internal beep speaker](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/Passthrough-internal-beep-speaker/m-p/981596)
in 2017 :

> Workstation 11.x and earlier will use the host internal beeper for
> virtual machine beeps on Windows hosts.  (I don't think we supported a
> virtual beeper on other host OSes in Workstation 11.x and possibly not
> for many releases into the past.)
>
> Workstation 12.0 and newer no longer include any support for the host
> internal beeper.  We had several compelling reasons to stop using the
> host's beeper, including: Host OS support for the beeper is
> hit-and-miss, many modern physical PCs no longer include beepers, and
> it's difficult to safely allow multiple VMs to concurrently share an
> inherently non-shareable host beeper.  So, we decided that Workstation
> 12 should no longer attempt to use the host beeper and will instead
> emulate beeps through the host's regular sound system.  This should
> function identically across all supported host OSes with multiple VMs
> running concurrently.
>
> If you absolutely need the host's beeper to be used, you'll need to
> run your VMs inside Workstation 11.x or earlier.

Going by the article, this is impossible, unless using the old
Workstation version 11.x.

Comment: nice try, but my problem is with VMWare, not VirtualBox ^^

Comment: Right, for VMWare there is no real solution. I updated my answer.

Comment: interesting, but this doesn't happen for me: ```will instead emulate beeps through the host's regular sound system.``` - it doesn't, there's no beep whatsoever

Comment: What sound system do you have, beside the speakers?

Comment: what do you mean by "sound system", hardware? got laptop speakers and a bluetooth headset (Sony wh-1000xm4), but i'm using the laptop speakers now

Comment: I do not have any such "console" beeps:  Host or Guest.  VMware Workstation 17, Windows 11 Host, several guests including Ubuntu 22 and Kali 2023

Comment: The beep is different from normal audio. In Windows at least this is a dedicated system call, which VMWare might have given up on intercepting, perhaps because it's too difficult with too many implementations for the different OS flavors and versions. Normal video+audio is much easier, because all it requires is to set up a virtual device implemented by VMWare, so no interception is required for system calls. I don't think that the problem with console beep can be solved.

Comment: @John here beep works both on Windows's cmd.exe (ctrl+G `^G` works) and works in Cygwin (`echo -ne "\a"` works) - but it doesn't work in VM clients :(